# How to change configuration variables in Ionic app when building/testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, gulp

I'm not familiar with the gulp tool so I'm not sure if that's what can solve this problem.

I have a ionic app that in its structure uses some global configuration variables defined inside the app.js file. when exporting the app for testing (ionic serve) those variables can have specific values like the server to which execute requests, etc. when exporting to device, those variables should be set differently.

What's the recommended way to have these two (or more) set of variables defined and how to incorporate it in the build workflow?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you... so I provide you my workaround

suppose that you have in your app.js theese lines

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
  /* if mobile */
    .value('mobile', 'some_config_mobile')
  /* if destkop */
    .value('desktop', 'some_config_desktop')
```

in your controllers/services you can do it

```
 angular.module('app')
    .service('myService', function (desktop,mobile){
       var config = (ionic.Platform.isWebView()) ? mobile : desktop; 
       //note: isWebView === true ---> you are in mobile
       //now you can use config wherever you are testing your app
});
```

Good luck